# React native Switch between tabs react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have 4 tab. I want to switch between tabs.

tab HOME
      -    stack example
      -    stack example

tab PROFILE 
      -    stack example
      -    stack example

tab IMAGE 
      -    stack example
      -    stack example

example: HOME -> PROFILE -> IMAGE -> press back button on device -> PROFILE ->  press back button on device -> HOME.

```
const MainTabs = TabNavigator({
Hometabs:{
  screen: HomeStack,
},
Profiletabs:{
  screen: ProfileStack,
},
Imagetabs:{
  screen: ImageStack,
},
Videotabs:{
  screen: VideoStack
 }
});
```

Comment: You can use `StackNavigator`

Comment: Each tabs, I have a stackNavigator. I don't think It possible. Can you explain more about solution?

Comment: So you don't want to show tabs on a single screen? as this facility is provided by tabnavigator